# Office 2010: add radio button

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I wanted to add a radio button to my document. But instead of seeing a radio button I see something like this:

[image: what word shows for one radio button]

So I wanted to ask you how I could get rid of the text (CONTROL FORMS...) to only see the button. I did deactivate the Design Mode but the text is still on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it.

Go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> scroll down to the 'Show document content' title and there is an option 'Show field codes instead of their values'. Deselect it.